# Analytic solution of particle in electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

This is homework and I need some guidance.
The question I struggle with is:

Place a particle with $m=2$ , $q=3$ in a constant electric field $\vec{E}=(5,0,0)$
Choose $\vec{r}(0)=(0,0,0)$ and $\vec{v}(0)=(0,0,0)$ and time steps $dt=1*10^{-4}$

I've nummerically found a solution using Euler-Cromer method in python and I set the acceleration vector $a=\frac{q\vec{E}}{m}$ Furthermore i must plot the motion in x direction with t, with this solution and in the same plot I must plot the analytic solution of x and t. The problem is what analytic solution.

from pylab import *

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from mpl_toolkits import *

q = 3.0

m = 2.0

dt = 1e-4

t0 = 0

t1 = 1

E = array([5.0, 0.0, 0.0])

t = linspace(t0, t1,(t1-t0)/dt)

n=len(t)

r = zeros((n,3))

v = zeros((n,3))

r[0] = array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

v[0] = array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])

a=q*E/m

for i in range(len(t)-1):

```
v[i+1] = v[i] + a*dt

r[i+1] = r[i] + v[i+1]*dt
```

figure("Exercize 1a og b", figsize=(12,10))

plot(t, r[:,0], label="$x_{direction}$")

title("Exercize 1a og b")

xlabel("time")

ylabel("position")

legend()

E=array([1.0,2.0,-5.0])

a=q*E/m

for i in range(len(t)-1):

```
v[i+1] = v[i] + a*dt

r[i+1] = r[i] + v[i+1]*dt
```

figure("Exercize 1c",figsize=(12,10))

plot(t, r[:,0], label="$x_{direction}$")

plot(t, r[:,1], label="$y_{direction}$")

plot(t, r[:,2], label="$z_{direction}$")

title("Exercize 1c")

xlabel("time")

ylabel("position")

legend()

show()

Both velocity ad position can be solved analytic. (And is what the motion is.)

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? An analytic expression of what? The particle's position?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the position as a function of time that you're looking for, matters are really quite simple. Ignoring gravity and all other forces (as you did in your numerical solution), we have a problem that is solved by one of the most basic equations from a freshman course in physics. If you know the general formula for the motion of a particle undergoing uniform acceleration, you just plug in the numbers: out rolls the correct answer.

Comment: That what i found out aswell -.-